# Error importing "FGDC Compliant Geology Symbology" into QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, geology

I have QGIS 3.18 running on Windows 10. Moreover, I downloaded FGDC Compliant Geology Symbology, and I downloaded and installed the FGDCGeoAge fonts, which appears as a font selection in drop down menus. Finally, I have restarted my laptop and QGIS several times. However, when I try to import the symbols there is an error. For example, when importing the contact.xml file, the symbols are incomplete and filled with question marks instead of the intended symbology.

Can anyone advise?

[image: Import Error]

[image: Incomplete Symbols]

Comment: Can you provide a download link?  That would really help.

Comment: I assume it's https://pubs.usgs.gov/tm/2006/11A02/